# How to convert a data reader to dynamic query results

Tags: c#, webmatrix

I have a View that typically gets query results from a WebMatrix Query (`IEnumerable<dynamic>` data type), and displays the results in a table:

```
@model MySite.Models.Entity
@foreach(var row in Model.Data)
{
    <tr>
        @foreach (var column in row.Columns)
        {
            <td>@column<span>:</span> @row[column]</td>
        }
    </tr>
}
```

Here's my model where I query the database:

```
public class Entity
{
    public dynamic Data {get; set; }
    public Entity(String table)
    {
        if (table == "User" || table == "Group)
        {
            WebMatrix.Data.Database db = new WebMatrix.Data.Database();
            db.Open(ConString);
            Data = db.Query("SELECT * FROM " + table);
        }
        else
        {
            using (OdbcConnection con = ne4w OdbcConnection(ConString))
            {
                OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand("Select * From " + table);
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                connection.Open();
                OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Here's all the different things I've tried from reading various other posts:

```
                // Atempt 1
                Data = reader;
                // Error in view, 'Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed' (on 'var row `in` Model.Data')

                // Atempt 2
                Data = reader.Cast<dynamic>;
                // Error: 'Cannot convert method group "Cast" to non-delegate type "dynamic". Did you intend to invoke the method?

                // Atempt 3
                Data = reader.Cast<IEnumerable<dynamic>>;
                // Error same as Atempt 2

                // Atempt 4
                Data = reader.Cast<IEnumerable<string>>;
                // Error same as Atempt 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking for the best way to get the reader object to a `IEnumerable<dynamic>` object.

*Please note this is a simplified example, and while the reason for the two query types is not obvious, they are necessary in my code.*

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211437/how-to-read-dynamic-properties-from-database

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You're missing basic C# syntax.

```
Data = reader;
// You cant do this. You have to loop the reader to get the values from it.
// If you simply assign reader object itself as the data you wont be 
// able to get data once the reader or connection is closed. 
// The reader is typically closed in the method.

Data = reader.Cast<dynamic>;
// You should call the Cast method. And preferably execute the resulting query. 
// As of now you're merely assigning method reference to a variable
// which is not what you want. 
// Also bear in mind that, as I said before there's no real benefit in casting to dynamic

Data = reader.Cast<IEnumerable<dynamic>>;
// Cast method itself returns an IEnumerable. 
// You dont have to cast individual rows to IEnumerable

Data = reader.Cast<IEnumerable<string>>;
// Meaningless I believe. 
// The data you get from database is not always strings
```

The major mistake you make is **not calling the method.** This is what you want:

```
Data = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>().ToList();
                               ^^ // notice the opening and closing parentheses
```

---

You could go about this a number of ways depending on what is easier to process (say, to display in front-end).

1. Return data records.

   ```
   public IEnumerable<IDataRecord> SelectDataRecord()
   {
       ....

       using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
           foreach (IDataRecord record in reader as IEnumerable)
               yield return record; //yield return to keep the reader open
   }
   ```
2. Return ExpandoObjects. **Perhaps this is what you wanted?**

   ```
   public IEnumerable<dynamic> SelectDynamic()
   {
       ....

       using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
           var names = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(reader.GetName).ToList();
           foreach (IDataRecord record in reader as IEnumerable)
           {
               var expando = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
               foreach (var name in names)
                   expando[name] = record[name];

               yield return expando;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Return sequence of property bag

   ```
   public IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> SelectDictionary()
   {
       ....

       using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
           var names = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(reader.GetName).ToList();
           foreach (IDataRecord record in reader as IEnumerable)
               yield return names.ToDictionary(n => n, n => record[n]);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Return sequence of plain object array

   ```
   public IEnumerable<List<object>> SelectObjectArray()
   {
       ....

       using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
           var indices = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).ToList();
           foreach (IDataRecord record in reader as IEnumerable)
               yield return indices.Select(i => record[i]).ToList();
       }
   }
   ```
5. Return data rows

   ```
   public IEnumerable<DataRow> SelectDataRow()
   {
       ....

       using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
           var table = new DataTable();
           table.BeginLoadData();
           table.Load(reader);
           table.EndLoadData();
           return table.AsEnumerable(); // in assembly: System.Data.DataSetExtensions
       }
   }
   ```
6. Last but not least, if it helps, you can return a strongly-typed sequence without any manual plumbing. You can use expression trees to compile code at run-time. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841120/generic-dbdatareader-to-listt-mapping) for e.g.

Comment: how would someone create an `async` version of the second option? I tried it and keep getting the following error: `The body of DbHelper.GetDataFromSproc(string sprocName, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)' cannot be an iterator block because 'Task<IEnumerable<dynamic>>' is not an iterator interface type`

Comment: @Code see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295119/asynchronous-iterator-taskienumerablet

Comment: This is THE ANSWER! Here I made good use of version 2 `ExpandoObject`. Thanks for sharing. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try looping the reader results:

```
OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read())
{
    var item = reader["yourField"].ToString();
}
```

It looks like you are just trying to set an object to the unexecuted IQueriable result of command.ExecuteReader();