# How to read dynamic sql columns into C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have an sql pivot query which results in dynamic sql columns. How do I read these values into a C# object?

I haven't had much success while I am able to read values from the datareader. I am unable to pack it into an object.

I need to use datareader and pass an object through the service layer to the UI.

sql code similar to below,

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME([MONTH]) 
                FROM #REVENUE
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

SELECT @query = 
'SELECT * FROM
(SELECT     
 [MONTH], 
SALES
FROM #REVENUE)X
PIVOT 
(
  AVG(SALES)
  for [MONTH] in (' + @cols + ')
) P

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Are all of the columns in the resultset named? If you use a function like `COUNT(*)` or possibly your pivot, the columns may not have a name. Ensure all the columns have a name which matches what you code expects.

Comment: able to read data but unable to proceed. as its dynamic i am stuck at the entity creation.

Comment: column names are dynamic vary like range of dates.

Comment: Please show us the query

Comment: query added to the question

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31656938/how-to-convert-a-data-reader-to-dynamic-query-results

Comment: Please show the object structure.

Comment: haven't been able to create object. since the columns are dynamic. columns could be MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG or JUN, JUL, AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV

Comment: @iceman : you may need to have class with x+1 number of fields, 1 field is for Header and remaining X fields are to store your data.

Answer (score 2):

If you select into a SQLDataReader, it has a [GetName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property which will return the column name.
Something like:

```
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(yourQuery, yourConnection)) {

        using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= reader.FieldCount; i++) {
                var name = reader.GetName(i);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: but what about the object / entity?

Comment: I'd properly just do a key/value store wrapped object - only other way I know (but haven't tried myself) would be ExpandoObject - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.100%29.aspx  - but it seems more trouble than it's worth.